# C# method returns connect to different databases

Tags: c#, database, oracle, advantage-database-server

**UPD:**
I have a static class for work with database.

This class contains the method which returns connect to database. Early this method returns connect to Advantage database (AdsConnection):

```
static private AdsConnection GetConnection(){
    var conn = new AdsConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
    return conn;
}
```

Now, I need to change this method. I need that this method returns connect to different databases types (Advantage database, Oracle database).

The method will work into public methods in my class. For example, method for get data from any table from database.

```
public static List<entity1> GetEntities(){}
```

Into this method the first of my step is to resolve the type of database, then  connect to database. Then get data from database and the last step is return data (List< entity1 >).

In the step to connect the database I need to use the method `GetConnection("Ads")`

This method returns current connect to database and then I can use this connect for work

I changed method:

**My first version**

```
static private T GetConnection<T>(string dbType)
        {
            if (dbType.Equals("Oracle"))
            {
                OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection
                conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
                return (T)conn;
            }

            if (dbType.Equals("Ads"))
            {
                AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection
                conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
                return (T)conn;
            }

            return default(T);
        }
```

But, my solution does not work. I have errors:

1. Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection' to 'T'
2. Cannot convert type 'Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsConnection' to 'T'
   I do not know how to resolve my problem.

Please, tell me how to resolve my problem?

**Now, I use the following code (this solution give me @khlr):**

```
static private IDbConnection GetConnection(string dbType)
{
    if (dbType.Equals("Oracle"))
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
        return conn;
    }

    if (dbType.Equals("Ads"))
    {
        AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
        return conn;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thank.

Comment: I think you need to re-read your code. Right now with current (incorrect) syntax I would be able to do (if we would forget about those syntax-errors for 5 min): `GetConnection<Integer>("Oracle")`.

Comment: Most of the Db client for .net implements from IDbConnection. So you can have IDbConnection as return type. Not necessarily have to be Generic type

Comment: I would personally recommend taking an entirely different approach.  Instead of creating this generalized connection factory, why not let consuming code simply instantiate their own connections in a simple `using` block?  Keep the scope/lifetime of the connection small, not global.

Comment: @David Excuse me, but I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain me more please?

Comment: @netwer: I mean that having a central "connection factory" like this has a strong tendency to lead to problems in the code.  When working with database connections, the use of `static` should be done *very* carefully.  It's often a much simpler pattern to just create the connection objects right where they're needed, not in a helper method like this.

Comment: @David Thank you for your response. I will accept note.

Comment: Or if you still want to have this as a central place, why not just have multiple methods? Presumably each caller knows the exact type they're expecting, so they could just call the right method...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are right, is one of way to resolve my problem. But, I need use one method - this is required by business rules

Comment: @netwer: What business rules? "Required by business rules" doesn't give any information about the reason behind that. If each caller requires a specific connection type, it's not like you're getting any benefit from being generic.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, if my answer doesn't give any information. I have a class which works with database. And I have a methods which do some operations with database. And I need to have the method which can connect to different databases. I need have only one method for connect to databases

Comment: Again, that doesn't say anything about *why* you need to have just one method. It also doesn't tell us about whether *any* of the calling code is database-agnostic. The more information you can give us, the more help we can give in making suggestions for the cleanest approach. (For example, is there always a single database in play? If so, why not put that information somewhere that the factory can detect it? Could you use dependency injection instead of a static class? There are all kinds of benefits in *not* using this sort of static access...)

Comment: @netwer: Unless the company literally sells database connection objects to customers, that's not really a "business rule".  Consider that any given consuming operation already needs to specify a type parameter (since there's no way to infer it), that's structurally no different than calling a separate method.  What's the benefit of the generic method?  It seems like the time already spent trying to get it to work is an indicator of the difficulty in supporting it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need some time to describe my question more detail. I will do it today. Thank.

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my question. I tried as much as possible to describe in detail my problem.

Comment: @netwer: You haven't explained *at all* why it's necessary to have a single method, nor do we even know whether your calling code can work with `IDbConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following, since both connections inherit from `IDbConnection`:

```
static private IDbConnection GetConnection(string dbType)
{
    if (dbType.Equals("Oracle"))
    {
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
        return conn;
    }

    if (dbType.Equals("Ads"))
    {
        AdsConnection conn = new AdsConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = here my connection string
        return conn;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can abstract the connection instantiation is by using DbProviderFactory of ADO.Net. You can basically pass it a provider name and it will give a connection based on the provider. This basically reduce the check of dbtype etc for you and I think its sensible approach when you need to target multiple database. Some of the code snippet are copied from MSDN.

In you config file you can multiple connection string set up with different database type and provider.

```
<configuration>
```

```
<add name="NorthwindAccess" 
 providerName="System.Data.OleDb" 
 connectionString=
 "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\Northwind.mdb;"
/>
```

Then in you method you can do following:

```
    static DbConnection CreateDbConnection(
    string providerName, string connectionString)
{
    // Assume failure.
    DbConnection connection = null;

    // Create the DbProviderFactory and DbConnection. 
    if (connectionString != null)
    {
        try
        {
            DbProviderFactory factory =
                DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);

            connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Set the connection to null if it was created. 
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection = null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    // Return the connection. 
    return connection;
}
```